# Does it make sense to compare on a dummy model?

Tags: classification

Say someone were to construct a binary classifier A on some variables. They want to determine whether those variables help with prediction or not.

So they build a second binary classifier which randomly spits out one of the two classes (with equal probability).

Now they statistically compare the predictions of both models and determine that the first model outperforms the second model. Now they claim that the variables indeed contribute towards the final prediction.

I do not know if it is valid to compare a model with a dummy model. I have seen this done in biological settings and financial settings. I don't know whether it makes sense to compare to a model that simply spits out random values.

Could someone elaborate how this is statistically valid? Is this formally the lift of the model?

Comment: It makes some sense to have a baseline against which to compare your model.  This gives you some idea how much better off you are using the model than not.  By the way, a better "null model" would be one that always predicts the class that's most likely using a simple proportion, not one that makes random guesses.

Comment: Hmm - neat. I see this often, yet I get a bad feeling in my stomach when this happens and people claim that their models work in comparison.

Comment: It only tells you that your model is better than nothing, but the model could still be terrible.

Comment: Is there a better baseline comparison? Or is this the best baseline that we can get?

Comment: Probably a better approach is to compare a model to reasonable alternatives rather than unreasonable ones such as those that use little or no information from the sample.